# How to extract email addresses from my string result and save them in a txt file one per line

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm fetching data from different sources and the output string looks like the following:

```
"addressId":"132234","businessEntryCount":2026},{"district":"Nordend-West","districtSlug":"frankfurt-am-main-nordend-west","addressId":"132232","businessEntryCount":1925}],"generated":"2022-01-23 19:35:43.469","grisuLocation":null,"district":null,"geo":null};
                kt.Data.SearchResult.distanceLocation = "Frankfurt am Main";
        kt.Data.SearchResult.distanceStreetnumber = "";
        kt.Service.citySlug = 'frankfurt';
        kt.Data.what = 'Handwerker';
        kt.Data.where = 'Frankfurt am Main';
        kt.Data.trade = 'Maler';
    

                {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"SearchResultsPage","mainEntity":{"@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdecker Olaf Pocklitz","url":"http:\/\/www.test.de","email":"test@t-online.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"65931","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen",
```

The above string content is my data result. I want to have only all the email addresses left to save them in a file. In the above example it would be test@t-online.de and if we have more than one email address, then I want the second email address in a new line. Im struggling how to perfectly filter them out and afterwards save them one by line. I already made it work to save it but I don't know how to only get the email address out of it:

```
console.log('received data: ' + data)
fs.writeFileSync('./results/test.json', data)
```

EDIT:

This is my code so far:

```
var matches = data.match(/\"mainEntity":{"(.*?)\"}/);
    var preResult = [matches]
    
    //.itemListElement[0].item.email
console.log('received data: ' + preResult)
fs.writeFileSync('./results/test.json', preResult)
```

and my result but im not able to access the email:

```
"mainEntity":{"@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdecker Olaf test","url":"http:\/\/www.test.de","email":"test@t-online.de","address":{....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this selector: `element.mainEntity.itemListElement[0].item.email`

```js
const element =  {
  "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
  "@type":"SearchResultsPage",
  "mainEntity":{
    "@type":"ItemList",
    "itemListElement":[
      {
        "@type":"ListItem",
       "item":{
         "@type":"LocalBusiness",
         "name":"Dachdecker Olaf Pocklitz",
         "url":"http:\/\/www.test.de",
         "email":"test@t-online.de",
         "address": ""
       }
      }
    ]
  }}

console.log(element.mainEntity.itemListElement[0].item.email)
```

### Update

```js
d = {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"SearchResultsPage","mainEntity":{"@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdecker Olaf Pocklitz","url":"http:\/\/www.pocklitz.de","email":"opocklitz@t-online.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"65931","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Erfurter Weg 21"},"telephone":"(069) 765820","aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","worstRating":1,"bestRating":5,"ratingValue":1,"reviewCount":3,"itemReviewed":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Dachdecker Olaf Pocklitz"}}}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdeckerei Havan","url":"http:\/\/www.dachdeckereihavan.de","email":"info@dachdeckereihavan.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60599","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Offenbacher Landstr. 364"},"telephone":"(069) 651540"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdeckerfachbetrieb Thomas Piller","email":"piller-bedachungen@gmx.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60439","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Eduard-Bernstein-Weg 3"},"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","worstRating":1,"bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"reviewCount":1,"itemReviewed":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Dachdeckerfachbetrieb Thomas Piller"}}}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dachdeckermeisterbetrieb Tuvana","url":"http:\/\/www.tuvana-dach.de","email":"info@tuvana-dach.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60596","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Tiroler Str. 28c"},"telephone":"(069) 78809681"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Decos GmbH","url":"http:\/\/www.decos-gmbh.de","email":"decosgmbh@web.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60388","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Flinschstr. 21"},"telephone":"(069) 42603940"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Dejan Miloradovic","email":"dmilo@web.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60487","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Sophienstr. 25"},"telephone":"(069) 703177"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Denstedt Bedachungs-GmbH","email":"denstedt.bedachungsgmbh@t-online.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60388","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Riedstr. 43"},"telephone":"(06109) 31967"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Der Zollstock - Ulrich Heuser & Hans-J\u00fcrgen Kurth","url":"https:\/\/www.der-zollstock.de","email":"kundenbetreuung@der-zollstock.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60388","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"R\u00f6ntgenstr. 8"},"telephone":"(06109) 378400"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Die Stadtzimmerei Stefan Scherer","url":"http:\/\/www.die-stadtzimmerei.de","email":"info@die-stadtzimmerei.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60385","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Wittelsbacherallee 102"},"telephone":"(069) 43059517"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"einfeldt Baudekoration GmbH","url":"https:\/\/www.einfeldt-baudeko.de","email":"info@einfeldt-baudeko.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60386","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Orber Str. 42"},"telephone":"(06039) 3878"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Emil Scholz GmbH & Co. KG","url":"https:\/\/www.malerteam-scholz.de","email":"info@malerteam-scholz.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60385","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Ostparkstr. 55"},"telephone":"(069) 943411-0","aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","worstRating":1,"bestRating":5,"ratingValue":1,"reviewCount":1,"itemReviewed":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Emil Scholz GmbH & Co. KG"}}}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Ewald Thamer","email":"ewald.thamer@t-online.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"65931","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Hesselbergweg 30"},"telephone":"(069) 36402623"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Falke Designs","email":"info@falke-designs.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60486","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Kaufunger Str. 16"},"telephone":"(0173) 8605872"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"FarbHey GmbH & Co.KG Malerfachbetrieb","url":"https:\/\/www.farbhey.de","email":"kontakt@farbhey.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60433","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Am Gr\u00fcnen Graben 20"},"telephone":"(069) 516309"}},{"@type":"ListItem","item":{"@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"FBM Boras Facility & Bau Management GmbH","url":"https:\/\/www.fbmgmbh.de","email":"info@fbmgmbh.de","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","postalCode":"60594","addressLocality":"Frankfurt","addressRegion":"Hessen","streetAddress":"Darmst\u00e4dter Landstr. 4"},"telephone":"(069) 63159155"}}],"name":"Alle Ergebnisse f\u00fcr Handwerker in Frankfurt online vergleichen"}}

console.log( d.mainEntity.itemListElement[0].item.email)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. im still stuck because I cant access the selector from the beginning. I did this: var matches = data.match(/\"mainEntity":{"(.*?)\"}/);
    var preResult = [matches] and now i have the part starting at: "mainEntity":{"@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@t.... but if I try to access the email it doesnt work. I cant even get access to itemListElement

Comment: @MarcelDz Can you share the whole json object in your question? It is possible?

Comment: @MarcelDZ `"email":"test@t-online.de","address":{... ` i mean the entire string without dots.

Comment: this is the whole string after i fetched the data: https://pastebin.com/EFndMmTM I need to only get the JSON first then I can access it like you showed me. But im not able to only have the JSON as result without the other stuff

Comment: line 162 in the pastebin example is what I only need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241359/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-marcel-dz).

Comment: thank you very much. but how can I only select the JSON? for me d is everything in the pastebin and not only the JSON